# Unclear description of DefaultFormatter's overwrite mode

Tags: java, swing, overwrite

If we look at the Java API for `DefaultFormatter`, we find that you can set it to two modes:

```
public void setOverwriteMode(boolean overwriteMode)
```

"Configures the behavior when inserting characters. If overwriteMode is `true` (the default), new characters overwrite existing characters in the model.

Parameters:
`overwriteMode` - Indicates if overwrite or overstrike mode is used"

The meaning of this is unclear. What is the practical difference between overwrite and overstrike mode? Can anyone who is familiar with `JFormattedTextField` or `AbstractFormatter`s please clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When `true`, it *overwrites* text as you type. Try it and see!

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18678843/230513. */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField("Xxxx yyy zzzz.");
        DefaultFormatter df = (DefaultFormatter) tf.getFormatter();
        df.setOverwriteMode(true);
        f.add(tf);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```